# In Matplotlib, try to store mouse positions in a dictionary. But it can only leave the last item

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, mouseevent, store

I tried to use Matplotlib in Python 3.7 to get a series of coordinators in a dictionary (or List). I want to use SHIFT with mouse left key to get current positions and store them in a temporary dictionary. Then I use CONTROL + mouse left key to add the temporary dictionary to a permanent dictionary. The code is attached. While I select a coordinator, I do not have trouble to add it to the permanent dictionary. I can even add the same coordinator multiple times. But whenever I try to get a new temporary coordinator, it wipes out all previous saved items in the permanent dictionary, except the last one. I do not want to use append in list since I might want to modify data previous stored (not sure here). Any idea?

```
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tmpDict={}
PermDict={}
i=0
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

def on_click(event):
    global tmpDict, PermDict, i
    # get the x and y pixel coords
    x, y = event.x, event.y

    if event.key=='shift':
        if event.button is MouseButton.LEFT:
            ax = event.inaxes  # the axes instance
            print('Data set: %d, data coords %f %f' % (i, event.xdata, event.ydata))
            tmpDict={'x':event.xdata, 'y':event.ydata}
            print(tmpDict)
            print(PermDict)

    if event.key=='control':
        if event.button is MouseButton.LEFT:
            ax = event.inaxes  # the axes instance
            PermDict={str(i):tmpDict}
            print(PermDict)
            i+=1

plt.connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do

```
PermDict[str(i)] = tmpDict
tmpDict = {}
```

instead of `PermDict={str(i):tmpDict}`

Comment: Thank you very much. I found to reset tmpDict={} is important. Indeed I was using PermDict[str(i)] = tmpDict in my full program. It always gives me funny results. Now after I put tmpDict={}, it behaves regularly.